# Xenserver API - Create VM's with local storage?

Tags: python, citrix, xen

I'm working with the API to create a utility for cloning a vm template. I'm borrowing a lot of code from the `install.py` example.

In our deployment we are using the local hard disk to store the `VM` images. The code example looks for a default storage repository, which doesn't exist if local storage is used exclusively. I have looked at the `XAPI` reference and I can't find any way to list local storage - this is necessary because I need the `UUID` of a storage repository to save the `VM` image to.

Comment: you should clearly point your question. What do you want to find out?

Comment: I am asking how to specify local storage, not a shared storage repository, as a clone destination for a VM using the XenServer API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get the `SR` object

```
sr_ref = self.session.xenapi.SR.get_by_uuid(local_storage_uuid)
```

Then get the `template` object which you want to clone

```
template = self.session.xenapi.VM.get_by_uuid(template_uuid)
```

Suggest a name for the VM that would be cloned

```
vm_id = "Test_Cone_VM"
```

Now If your `template repo` and the `cloned VM repo` is same then use `Async.VM.clone` . And if the repos are different then use `Async.VM.copy`

```
self.session.xenapi.Async.VM.copy(template, vm_id, sr_ref)
```

or

```
self.session.xenapi.Async.VM.clone(template, vm_id)
```

Have a look at the [Xenserver API](http://docs.vmd.citrix.com/XenServer/6.0.0/1.0/en_gb/api/?c=VM) for more info.